# Android Java Exceptions - How do they work when thrown manually?

Tags: java, android, exception

I am interested in how exceptions in Android work when trown manually.
I tried to make an app where you can push a button and a random exception would popup.
Here I noticed something strange. When for instance, I throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, I get an IlligalStateException.

Function that generates exception:

```
public void GenerateRandomException(View view)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int random = rand.nextInt(5);

    switch(random)
    {
        case 0:
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occured!");
        case 1:
            throw new RuntimeException("A RuntimeException occured!");
        case 2:
            throw new NullPointerException("An NullPointerException occured!");
        case 3:
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException("An IllegalThreadStateException occured!");
        case 4:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("An IllegalArgumentException occured!");
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occured!
    at gamebugtracker.lib.MainActivity.GenerateRandomException(MainActivity.java:78)
    ... 14 more
```

As seen in the stacktrace, it says there is an IlligalStateEception, caused by the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
I find this strange, shouldn't the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, be the top exception?
Or did I broke my own code?

Comment: Because the classes are loaded through a ClassLoader (or something of the sort), you are seeing that loader catching, and rethrowing the exception to you.

Comment: I find that I always have to skim down to a `"Caused by:"` line to find out what the real exception is (whether I throw it manually or because of a real bug).  It's normal.  The stuff above it  is just there because of how Android works, and most of us can ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, your `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is the bottommost "caused by" exception in the stack trace.

There are other `catch` blocks in between that catch your exception and wrap it to another exception using [`Exception(String,Throwable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) constructor. In this case this wrapper code is in the [code that transforms your XML `onClick` declaration to a `OnClickListener`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#3789), with the intermediate `InvocationTargetException` coming from Java reflection.

Ultimately the exception gets caught by the top-level exception handler that logs it as "FATAL EXCEPTION" and terminates your app. The log output includes all nested exceptions as well.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But when for instance I would want to log these exceptions, would it be wise to save the top one, or the lowest one, where the exception occured?

Comment: Log the full topmost exception. The stacktrace automatically includes the nested exceptions.

Comment: Clear answers. Thank you!